# How do I get the timestamp for each likes on a particular post on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

I need to get the time stamp for all likes a post has on Instagram.
The API doesn't support this. Is there a method or unofficial API to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This question has a few duplicates. It's not easy get timestamps for Instagram likes and other actions because there's no time tracking on their website for likes, it's not built into their APIs, and this data is probably too valuable for them to not keep internal.

I favor [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356500/instagram-likes-per-time) which suggests scraping lists of likes at some interval every day so that you can track likes grouped by time periods.

Instagram's APIs don't seem to support timestamp tracking for likes, and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957984/api-access-to-instagram-notification-feed), they may have removed endpoints that could've made it possible.

I use a python module called [instaloader](https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader) which is an unofficial option for scraping all sorts of Instagram account data.

[As answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592250/get-list-of-users-who-commented-or-liked-post-on-instagram-with-python), you can use instaloader's `get_likes()` method to loop through each post and scrape lists of usernames that liked each post.

To install, use `pip3 install instaloader`

If you don't auth with a real Instagram login, you may get an error 429. Login is simple:

```
#login
username = "YOUR_USERNAME"
password = "YOUR_PASSWORD"

L.login(username, password)
```